# Как сравнить char и string c++?

Tags: c++

Имеется такой код:

```
int analysis::_indexOfSymbol(char symbol, std::string* alphabet, int size) {

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if(symbol == alphabet[i]) return i;
}

return NULL;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку, что невозможно сравнить `int` и `строку`. Хотя, `symbol` является типом `char`(да, это буквенный эквивалент кода, но тем не менее). Я пытался преобразовать `symbol` к `string`, но ни `(std::string)` `symbol`, ни `std::string(symbol)`, ни `std::string k = std::symbol(symbol)` мне не помогли. Точно также, я пытался преобразовать `alphabet[i]` в `char`(ВНИМАНИЕ! В массиве array хранятся строковые значения, но односимвольные), но у меня ничего не вышло из-за различия типов `char*` и `char`.

Код, который создает alphabet выглядит примерно так:

```
this->alphabet[0] = "А"; this->alphabet[1] = "Б"; и т.д.
```

Comment: `sizeof(alphabet)` o_O А какое, вы думаете, значение этого выражения?

Comment: Вы бы код, который `alphabet` создает привели... (а то, слова ТС это только его слова)

Comment: Раз `alphabet` и в самом деле массив указателей на строки, то в `_indexOfSymbol` вместе с ним надо передавать его размер (или завершать этот массив нулевым указателем (аналогично `argv[]` в параметрах `main()`)

Comment: ну, я там поправил. Он сейчас передает.

Comment: Ответ вообще-то уже есть, я его там ниже написал, но здесь не добавил размер массива, сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вот так:

```
if(alphabet[i].size() == 1 && alphabet[i][0] == symbol) return i;
```

будет наиболее эффективно.

Comment: А, т.е. т.к. у меня есть массив строк, то я могу сначала обратиться к элементу массива, а затем к 0-му элементу строки. Здорово)
Но условие как по мне длинновато)

Comment: Сделайте заменяющий его макрос (или `static inline` функцию)

Answer (score 4):

У вас `alphabet` — не строка, а *указатель* на строку. Ну и `sizeof(alphabet)` выдаёт размер указателя (то есть, 4 или 8, в зависимости от вашей платформы), а не размер строки.

Кроме того, размер `std::string` считается не так. Сама строка выделяется где-то в куче, а `sizeof` выдаёт размер лишь самого объекта, то есть, содержащихся в нём указателей.

Правильный цикл такой:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet->size(); ++i) {
    if (symbol == (*alphabet)[i]) return i;
}
```

Кроме того, финальный `return NULL`, судя по всему, неправильный, ведь `NULL` — это просто 0, и значит, возвращаемое значения будет выглядеть как будто бы символ нашёлся на нулевой позиции.

---

Впрочем, вы можете просто не строить велосипед, а воспользоваться встроенной функцией поиска: `alphabet->find(symbol)`. Если символ не найден, она вернёт константу `std::string::npos`.

---

Если указатель на самом деле соответствует *массиву* строк, то вы должны передавать его размер отдельным параметром:

```
int analysis::_indexOfSymbol(char symbol, std::string* alphabet, size_t array_size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
        // здесь можно искать вхождение символа:
        auto pos = alphabet[i].find(symbol);
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
            return i;
    }

    return -1; // или какое-то другое значение, не могущее быть индексом
}
```

Достать размер массива из указателя нельзя.

Альтернативный путь — использовать вместо массива (ссылку на) `std::vector`, вот он-то как раз знает размер своих данных.

[Или можно сделать метод шаблонным, и принимать `std::array`, но этот вариант может и подойти, если размер данных динамический.]

Comment: На `return NULL;` компилятор будет немного ругаться

Comment: А если у ТС alphabet это в самом деле массив string (std::string ab[256];)? Тогда о каком `->size()` идет речь?

Comment: Вы не совсем на то ответили. alphabet это массив строк, а не строка.
Проблема в сравнении с элементом массива,а не со строкой alphabet.

Comment: За find спасибо, не знал о ней.

Comment: @kot_mapku3: Окей, обновил ответ.

Comment: @avp: Вы были правы :-)

Comment: @VladD я тоже обновил вопрос, не уверен, что стоило минусовать, но в самом начале я уже дал ответ на свой вопрос.
Спасибо больше.

Comment: @kot_mapku3: Минус не мой, я только ответил. // Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Подключи `<string>` и используй `std::to_string`. 
Для твоего случая:
`std::to_string(symbol)`.